# Error al crear Job ORACLE ---ORA-06550

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, jobs

estoy creando un Job en Oracle, la cual ejecutara todos los dias a las 00:00 Horas un procedimiento almacenado.
Al crearlo arroja el siguiente error.

```
Fallo al procesar el comando SQL
- ORA-06550: línea 19, columna 5:
PLS-00103: Se ha encontrado el símbolo "DBMS_SCHEDULER" cuando se esperaba uno de los siguientes:


   ;
El símbolo ";" ha sido sustituido por "DBMS_SCHEDULER" para continuar.
```

Este es el codigo.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
            job_name => '"VINCULADO"."JobBorrado"',
            job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
            job_action => 'VINCULADO.ELIMINACIONLOG',
            number_of_arguments => 0,
            start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2022-02-01 00:00:00.000000000 AMERICA/BOGOTA','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
            repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYTIME=230000;BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN',
            end_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2050-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 AMERICA/BOGOTA','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
            enabled => FALSE,
            auto_drop => FALSE,
            comments => '');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE( 
             name => '"VINCULADO"."JobBorrado"', 
             attribute => 'logging_level', value => DBMS_SCHEDULER.LOGGING_OFF);
  
null
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
             name => '"VINCULADO"."JobBorrado"');
END;
```

Al procedimiento almacenado al hacerle un EXECUTE, lo ejecuta sin problema.

Comment: Leyendo en otros lugares, te pregunto: ¿están el job y el procedure en el mismo schema?

Comment: Siii, están en el mismo esquema.